# Handling revoking In-App purchase with iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, storekit

I added the new revocation API provided with iOS 14 but i'm still confused about some aspect of it. I tested revoking my subscription using [StoreKit Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/setting_up_storekit_testing_in_xcode) and I do enter in the `didRevokeEntitlementsForProductIdentifiers` callback.

But I'm wondering if this will cover all the cases where apple actually revoke access to a user because the user asked for a Refund. What happen if the app is closed? Will this method be called upon launching the app the next time?

Here is my code:

```
extension PurchaseManager: SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        /*no-op*/
    }

    @available(iOS 14, *)
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, didRevokeEntitlementsForProductIdentifiers productIdentifiers: [String]) {
        SubscriptionHandler().validateSubscription()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I understand `paymentQueue(_:didRevokeEntitlementsForProductIdentifiers:)` will be invoked when a refund request is granted, as well as if their access to the product changes. For example, with Family Sharing, they may cancel the subscription or leave the family. Note though that they may still have access to the purchased product so one should examine the receipt to know whether or not to revoke access (local receipt validation or via your server). For more information, see this [WWDC 2020 video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10661/) and the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymenttransactionobserver/3564804-paymentqueue).

If your app is not running, I understand `paymentQueue(_:didRevokeEntitlementsForProductIdentifiers:)` can be invoked when your app is launched next once you add an observer via `SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)`, similar to how `paymentQueue(_:updatedTransactions:)` works.

Comment: Nice and comprehensive answer @Jordan. I would add that you should be an observer to the payment queue for the lifetime of the app. So as soon as the app launches in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions until it is killed. This will mean you don't miss out on any of these callbacks.